# Java - Simple Tax Calculator using If and if else statements(2)

Tags: java, if-statement

**The Problem with My Code:**

- `TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income);` -> underlined with red
- `else ((Income > 200000))` -> shows error `" ';' is expected"`

Here's the code....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeProbLab4 {


 /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter your Income: ");
  String In = sc.nextLine();
  Double Income = Double.parseDouble(In);

  double TotalTax;
  TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income);
  System.out.println("Your taxes are: " + TotalTax);
 }

 static double calculateAndPrintTax(double Income, double TotalTax) {
  double tax;
  double difftax1;
  double difftax2;
  double difftax3;
  double difftax4;

  if ((Income >= 45282) && (Income <= 200000)) {
   if (Income <= 45282) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    TotalTax = tax;
   } else if (Income > 45282 && Income <= 90653) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
    TotalTax = tax + difftax1;
   } else if ((Income > 90563) && (Income <= 140388)) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
    difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
    TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2;
   } else if ((Income > 140388) && (Income <= 200000)) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
    difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
    difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
    TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3;
   } else if ((Income > 200000)) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
    difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
    difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
    difftax4 = (Income - 200000) * 0.33;
    TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3 + difftax4;
   } else((Income > 200000)) {
    tax = 45282 * 0.15;
    difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
    difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
    difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
    difftax4 = (Income - 200000) * 0.33;
    TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3 + difftax4;

   }
   return TotalTax;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is due to the signature of the method you're calling.

`static double calculateAndPrintTax(double Income, double TotalTax)` expects two doubles to be passed to it. You attempt to only send one.

`TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income); // you need another double value.`

**But that's unnecessary** in the first place. You try to pass the total tax to a method that calculates the total tax. In fact, you don't even use the value it may hold before you assign it a new one. So, remove that from the signature of the method to make it...

```
calculateAndPrintTax(double Income) {
    // ...and add...
    double TotalTax = 0;
}
```

...at the top to replace the one you're passing. And call it like you originally did.

```
TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income);
```

That's actually not your best option but changing what you have in this answer would be too much.

The second problem is as it suggests; an `else/if` has a condition, not a typical `else`. So, either make it an `if/else` or remove the condition. I'm guessing maybe the latter is more appropriate since it is an exact duplicate of the condition in the `if/else` above.

An additional note not directly related to your problems - I think it would be wise to look carefully at the code and notice how much of it is repeated and try to figure out a way to make it more concise.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes however and added TotalTax to TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income, TotalTax), However TotalTax in the brackets is underlined in red...

Comment: @R.Bar, I trust if the edit addressing the above comment fixes your issue you will accept this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, Also, please let me know how to update this post with the new code as I am new to stackoverflow, Thanks

Comment: @R.Bar, typically you wouldn't fix the errors in the code you posted. By accepting the answer you're saying the issue's resolved using this method. If you happen to fix something on your own you can answer your own question with the fix if you like. I just [did that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661457/how-to-configure-the-coverage-plugin-to-append-coverage-suites) earlier today.

Comment: So no new advice, too touch to answer?

Comment: @R.Bar, no, I did answer it in the edit to the answer. It begins at the bold part.

Comment: Okay, so I added the TotalTax=0; inside the method and it worked. The program ran, however when I entered a number greater than 200000, it just returned 0 and didn't perform the calculation.

Comment: Also, I do not understand what you mean when you talk about the if/else statements

Comment: I'm going to leave it up to the person whose answer you've accepted continue to help you. You're seeing the exact output one would expect based on your code. I can't spoon feed you the answer to all your problems. And it seems you're not putting much effort into it. @R.Bar

Comment: That was a mistake, you deserve the acceptance, and just gave it to you.

Comment: Its not that im not putting in effort, I've done everything that I can think of that makes logical sense. Anyways, I figured it out, I had to change the first If, which only limited Income up to 200000. Just have a question I hope you can answer: what would you set the method as, so it would return both a double and/or a string, is that possible. THANKS

Comment: @R.Bar, I am glad you were able to figure that part out.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple errors;

`static double calculateAndPrintTax(double Income, double TotalTax)` is the signature of the `calculateAndPrintTax` method, you should supply two `double` values to it.

Other problem is that in `else` claus, you do not give any conditions. You should rather use `else if(condition)`

Comment: I have made the necessary changes however and added TotalTax to TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income, TotalTax), However TotalTax in the brackets is underlined in red...

Comment: It must be due to declaring it without any value. Start with this; `double TotalTax = 0`