# How to configure the Coverage plugin to append coverage suites?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

[Coverage](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-coverage.html) is a plugin for IntellijIDEA (going back many releases). It captures code coverage statistics for a given run configuration.

According to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html) we should be able to append the results for multiple runs either by selecting it as the default behavior or by having Intellij prompt for the settings before applying coverage to the editor.

But the settings never seem to get applied. If I choose to be prompted; I'm never prompted. If I choose to append them; they're never appended. One member on my team says they *are* prompted but the results do not reflect their choice.

I've tried everything I can think of:

1. Manually changed settings for Coverage in my workspace.xml file
2. Deactivated and reactivated Coverage
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled Coverage
4. Tried using the other runners for Coverage (Emma and JaCoCo)
5. Even uninstalled and reinstalled Intellij with hopes I was carrying around faulty settings from a previous install.

Nothing works.

Am I missing something obvious; how do I configure Coverage to append coverage suites? I'm thinking it's a bug but is there perhaps some workaround possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround but it doesn't involve appending the suites and it's a bit ugly.

I can't find a way to fix appending suites but coverage is applied to run configurations. So, what you can do if you have an existing suite you want to add to, you can add another run configuration and run with coverage to generate a suite for that run.

What you end up with is a number of suites you then have to merge; the merging functionality in Coverage works. Note that no coverage suites are *appended*; no new files are generated. It simply merges the results into the coverage view allowing a total report to be generated.

---

To view merged coverage data:

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F6`
2. Choose one or more coverage suites to merge
3. Click "Show selected"

A view of the merged suite data should appear in the editor.

---